# iOS mapview : Custom callout view position adjustment

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I am working on a mapview where on click of any annotation pin, I am showing custom callout view.
But the problem is, part of this view is going out of screen.
Is there any way by which I can adjust mapview to show full callout view just like default callout view?

Comment: [This callout](https://github.com/nfarina/calloutview) adjusts automatically, and has a very nice function which handles it

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple demo project on custom callout view of mapkit. This might help you.

https://github.com/NabinRai4017/CallOutExample

Comment: Generally, links to a tool or library [should be accompanied by usage notes, a 
specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, or some 
sample code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605), or if possible all of the above.